# Simple binding not working

Tags: angularjs

In the below snippet, I'm not able to print a simple value of `search_username`.

**HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="GibtHubViewer">

  {{search_username}} <!-- not getting displayed -->

  <form name="searchUser">
    <br/>
    <input type="search" placeholder="Username to search" ng-model="search_username" />
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
  </form>

  <br/>

  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    {{userdata.name}} {{error}}
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**JS Code:**

```
// Code goes here


var MainController = function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.search_username = "anyname"; // Value assigned here


  var onComplete = function(response) {
    $scope.userdata = response.data;
  }

  var onError = function(reason) {
    $scope.error = "Not able to fetch data";
  }

  var request = $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/angular");

  request.then(onComplete, onError);



}

var myModule = angular.module("GibtHubViewer", []);

myModule.controller("MainController", ["$scope", "$http", MainController]);
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your model out of scope. you should put all model in scope that define it by controller.

```
 <body ng-app="GibtHubViewer" ng-controller="MainController">

  {{search_username}} <!-- not getting displayed -->

 <form name="searchUser">
       <br/>
   <input type="search" placeholder="Username to search" ng-model="search_username" />
   <input type="submit" value="search" />
   </form>

   <br/>

   <div >
    {{userdata.name}} {{error}}
   </div>

   </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The position where you are trying to print the model is out of Scope of the controller which is used, try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="GibtHubViewer" ng-controller="MainController">

      {{search_username}} <!-- not getting displayed -->

      <form name="searchUser">
        <br/>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Username to search" ng-model="search_username" />
        <input type="submit" value="search" />
      </form>

      <br/>

      <div>
        {{userdata.name}} {{error}}
      </div>

    </body>


    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to display the `{{search_username}}` outside the controller area.

the `search_username` is added in the scope in `MainController` but you are trying to print that outside the `MainController`'s area.

`<div ng-controller="MainController">
   {{userdata.name}} {{error}} 
search_username - {{search_username}} // This will print the username
  </div>`